# Prestashop 1.7 Modules catalog data not found

Tags: php, apache, ssl, module, prestashop-1.7

So i installed PrestaShop 1.7 on my local (keep in mind my local works perfectly find) moved it over to live staging (had no database import or exporting errors or installation errors),but for some reason everything works but if i open the CMS logged in, and i click on the tab "Modules & Services" i get the following message with a "try again" call to action button underneath the message.

**"Cannot get catalog data, please try again later. Reason: Data from PrestaShop Addons is invalid, and cannot fallback on cache"**

So i tried clearing cache, tried searching for answers , but found unsecured replies which i cant rely on.

Also in my "Modules & Services" when i click on the tab "Installed modules" i get an "RequestException in RequestException.php line 51" saying SSL CA bundle not found, so my modules is broken , i did see im not the only one with this problem but havent seen any fix on this?

Also could it be that on my Apache server the SSL is blocking this module? which means i would have to get access because at this moment i do not have access.

Also i tried this secured sulotion, tripple checked all my changes still got the same exact error message. (https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/6848/files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i have not tried this becuase i have moved back to version 1.6, but for anyone with the same problem, prestashop developer posted this to my question,just follow link.

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/569275-prestashop-17-modules-catalog-data-not-found/#entry2463881

my solution was download the file https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save into /app/cache/prod/. The problem exist because if the production cache is deleted then the file cacert.pem is deleted too.

I check in https://github.com/P...pull/6848/files and in my offline copy that file classes/Tools.php have the constant declaration:

```
const CACERT_LOCATION = 'https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem';
```

and that file must exist in:

```
_PS_CACHE_DIR_.'cacert.pem'
```

as you can see in this global definition:

```
define('_PS_CACHE_CA_CERT_FILE_', _PS_CACHE_DIR_.'cacert.pem')
```

so, I chek if the file cacert.pem exist in production cache and it was deleted...I hope this help. (ref, mrbrazzi)

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem and fixed it.

I had the 'js' folder misplaced (for some unknown reason) and incomplete, so I downloaded the 'js' and 'themes' original folders form https://github.com/prestashop/prestashop and replaced them.

Comment: Thanks for your response , i feel like i have so much bad luck with this new prestashop 1.7. I just went back to the previous version(1.6.1.9), but i did tried your solution for the bug fix and im honest when i say its just not working, my 'js' directory was there (complete), but i replaced it as you said, same with theme, my problem stays the same...thanks again wish it worked for me aswell.